# How to map child (leaf-level) nodes to specific parents with/without ltree for aggregations?

Tags: postgresql, performance, group-by, aggregate, hierarchy

**What would be the best way to aggregate across hierarchies?**

I am using Postgres and have the following 3 tables (`folder`, `folder_hierarchies`, and `work`) -

1. `folder`

| Column | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| folder_id (pk) | uuid | UUID for folder |
| org_id (pk) | uuid | Org ID where the folder belongs |
| name | text | Textual name of the folder |
| type | text | What level is the folder at? Example -> home, floor, apartment_complex, locality, suburb |
| created_at | timestamptz | Time when the folder was created |

2. `folder_hierarchies`

| Column | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| folder_id (pk) | uuid | fk reference of folder_id from folder table |
| org_id (pk) | uuid | fk reference of org_id from folder table |
| parent (fk) | uuid | fk reference of folder_id from folder table - denoting parent of current folder |
| path | ltree | ltree definition for the current folder |

3. `work`

| Column | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| work_id (pk) | uuid | UUID for work |
| org_id | uuid | Org ID where the work was done |
| folder_id | uuid | Folder on which the work was done |
| created_at | timestamptz | Time when the work was done |

The `folder` is nothing but a hierarchy, think of it as a file system, running at most 5 levels deep. `work` is done at the leaf-node of the `folder` hierarchy, i.e., if the `type = home`. Now, a `home` can have any type of `parent`, it could be one of -

- null (in which case `parent` is '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' and `ltree` is the `folder_id` of the `home` itself)
- `floor` (so `ltree` for home becomes `floor_id.home_id`)
- `apartment_complex` (so `ltree` for home becomes `apartment_complex_id.floor_id.home_id`)
- `locality` (so `ltree` for home becomes `locality_id.apartment_complex_id.floor_id.home_id`)
- `suburb` (so `ltree` for home becomes `suburb_id.locality_id.apartment_complex_id.floor_id.home_id`)

Below is a sample representation of the hierarchy -
[image]

Okay, so that's the setup.

What I'm looking to do is aggregate work count by various hierarchy levels -

1. Aggregate total `work` count by `home` (straightforward)
2. Aggregate total `work` count by `floor`
3. Aggregate total `work` count by `apartment_complex`
4. Aggregate total `work` count by `locality`
5. Aggregate total `work` count by `suburb`

The Postgres instance is queried by an engine that maintains pre-aggregations of data. Leveraging that, I thought the best way would be to separate each of the different rollups into different views (or cubes). Like one view for `home <> floor` mapping, another for `home <> apartment_complex` mapping and so on.

**What would be the best way to do this?**

Here's some sample work that I have done. It works, but I'm not proud of it, and I'm worried that the performance might be very slow.

**1. Aggregate total `work` by `floor`** ->

```sql
-- Maintain home <> floor mapping (pre-aggregation)
SELECT h.folder_id as home, h.parent as floor_id 
    FROM folder_hierarchies h JOIN folders f ON f.folder_id = h.parent 
    WHERE f.meta_label = 'floor';

-- Count work done per floor
SELECT
  `home_floor__floor_id` `home_floor__floor_id`,
  `work__created_at_day` `work__created_at_day`,
  sum(`work__count`) `work__count`
FROM
  dev_pre_aggregations.home_floor_rollup_home_floor AS `home_floor__rollup_home_floor`
  LEFT JOIN dev_pre_aggregations.work_rollup_work AS `work__rollup_work` ON `home_floor__home_id` = `work__home_id`
WHERE
  (
    `work__created_at_day` >= to_timestamp(?)
    AND `work__created_at_day` <= to_timestamp(?)
  )
GROUP BY
  1,
  2
ORDER BY
  3 DESC
LIMIT
  10000
```

2. Aggregate total `work` by `suburb` (using `ltree`)

```sql
-- Maintain home <> suburb mapping (pre-aggregation)
SELECT child.folder_id AS home_id, suburb.folder_id AS suburb_id
          FROM ${homesFolderHierarchiesTable} child
                 JOIN ${homesFolderHierarchiesTable} suburb ON child.path <@ suburb.path
                 JOIN ${homesFoldersTable} suburb_folder
                      ON suburb_folder.meta_label = 'suburb' AND suburb_folder.folder_id = suburb.folder_id
                 JOIN ${homesFoldersTable} child_folder
                      ON child_folder.meta_label = 'home' AND child_folder.folder_id = child.folder_id

-- Count work done per suburb
SELECT
  `home_suburb__suburb_id` `home_suburb__suburb_id`,
  sum(`work__count`) `work__count`
FROM
  dev_pre_aggregations.home_suburb_rollup_home_suburb AS `home_suburb__rollup_home_suburb`
  LEFT JOIN dev_pre_aggregations.work_rollup_work AS `work__rollup_work` ON `home_suburb__home_id` = `work__home_id`
GROUP BY
  1
ORDER BY
  2 DESC
LIMIT
  10000
```